# Mysql Escape function; Generate Update Query by using Select Query

Tags: mysql

Hello
i have an development server and production server on both are the same databases.
The table products will be edited on both servers but only on different columns
Development: id model image
Production: price and out_of_stock

i don't want use php for this.

so i have created following query for the development server

```
SELECT CONCAT( "UPDATE `products` SET `products_id` = ", products_id, ",`products_model` = '", REPLACE( products_model, "'", "\'" ) , "',`products_image` = '", products_image, "' WHERE `products`.`products_id` = ", products_id, ";" )
FROM `products`
```

this query return me the query for the production sever

```
UPDATE `products` SET `products_id` = 60,`products_model` = 'CT'257',`products_image` = 'ct_black01.jpg' WHERE `products`.`products_id` = 60;
UPDATE `products` SET `products_id` = 59,`products_model` = 'CT"255',`products_image` = 'ct_black01.jpg' WHERE `products`.`products_id` = 59;
UPDATE `products` SET `products_id` = 58,`products_model` = 'CT/242',`products_image` = 'ct_black01.jpg' WHERE `products`.`products_id` = 58;
UPDATE `products` SET `products_id` = 57,`products_model` = 'CT221',`products_image` = 'ct_black01.jpg' WHERE `products`.`products_id` = 57;
```

the problem is that i need to escape the fields when the product_model contain ' or " or both
then this query will fail

how i can do mysql_real_escape without php?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(products_model, "'", "\\'"), '"', '\\"')
```

This will replace all single and double quotes with escaped single and double quotes.